# Is deeply nested view hierarchy in iOS ok?

Tags: ios, uiview

In Android it is recommended that the view hierarchy depth be kept under 10, and strictly under 20 or else your app is very likely to perform poorly or crash (UI thread only a tiny 8-16kB of stack space)

Does this hold true for iOS, with or without autolayout (why or why not) ?

Comment: Can you explain why this is an issue? 10-deep seems overkill.

Comment: In android its possible to go >10 with complex layouts if you don't plan it correctly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update:

It is actually quite bad if you are using autolayout, as constraints solving has polynomial complexity (cassowary is linear in the sense that it solves *linear* equations)

1. http://floriankugler.com/2013/04/22/auto-layout-performance-on-ios/
2. http://pilky.me/36/

UIView itself is very fast as posts here suggest, however. I ended up replacing autolayout with an alternative system.

**TLDR: UIView/CALayer is fast. Autolayout is not.**

Answer (score 2):

Views in iOS are backed by OpenGL and have amazing performance. I've personality gone as deep as 50 views with no problems. I don't recommend making the depth bigger than necessary, but when the situation calls for it, it is viable.

Answer (score 1):

I've never seen any such recommendation for iOS. As always, you should implement your code and view hierarchy as straightforward as possible. After that, measure your performance and tweak if needed. Avoid premature optimization as much as possible.

Comment: Yup premature optimization is bad, but it is good to be aware

Comment: @nehz Yes, and as @Neal says, `UIView`/`CALayer` is backed by OpenGL and drawing performance is very good.